# How to use a list name in the name of the figure?

Tags: string, r, list, filenames

I have created several list enviroments. Then I wrote a function to draw several figures from the stored data and I would like to use a list name as a part of figure name.

```
list_xName <- list(aa = 1:10, bb = exp(-3:6), cc=-3:6)  
drawL<-function(list_xName){
plot(list_xName$aa,list_xName$bb)
savePlot(filename=paste("fig_",xxxxxxx,sep=""),type="eps")  
}
```

Instead of 'xxxxxxx' in savePlot I would like to have a name of the list.

I hope that my question is understandeble enough. Thank you in advance.

Comment: try `deparse(substitute(list_xName))`

Comment: @Anja -- Try running the code you've posted to see how reproducible it is!

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, did you mean my typing mistakes in code above (already corrected, - instead of <-) or anything else? My code works fine with baptiste 's suggestion

Comment: @babtiste, I think that you should post your comment as an answer that I can 'grade' it as useful

Comment: Anja -- Thanks for fixing both the `<-` and the `xvname` bits. It looked like you were referring to an object you hadn't provided. Also, I'll type '@baptiste' so he's alerted to your comment.

Comment: @baptiste you may want to write your comment as an answer so that Anja can accept it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `deparse(substitute(list_xName))`